# Functions in Wordpress function.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've started building a theme for Wordpress. Add a certain point I want to add some style to the site. I can get it to work when adding the style to the header, but I want to use the function.php file to accomplish this. This is what I got:

```
<?php
function addCss(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css');
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "addCss");
?>
```

It's a very simple function, but for some reason, the function is not fired. I also don't get any errors and style.css is not added to the site according to the console.

My file structure:

[image]

I've tried searching for a solution, but couldn't find any. I hope u guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.php just before ending `</head>` tag.

```
function addMyStyle() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );

}
add_action('wp_head', 'addMyStyle');
```

Comment: Unfortunately no result. I even replaced mine code with yours and added <?php wp_head(); ?>  just before the </head> tag.

Comment: it is tested code, it is working fine, try disable plugin and check your file is loading or not.

Comment: I got it working! Your solution was great, but I needed to change 'wp_head' @add_action into: 'wp_enqueue_scripts'.
Thx for helping!

Answer (score 0):

get_template_directory_uri() return a path without the "/" at the end.

Add a "/" in your path:

```
// add this line to create a versionning of your stylesheet
$ver = time();
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', $ver);
```

I hope that help you !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've did like u said, but with no result.

Comment: Did you use your function in functions.php and not in header.php ?

Maybe remove $ver :
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

Answer (score 0):

You need to have wp_head() in header.php

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'themescripts' ) ) {
    function themescripts() {
            wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array());

            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', array(), '', true);
            ....
        }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themescripts' ); 
}
```

Also, make sure to have wp_footer() in footer.php file.